# Dragging a window in GNOME 3 is very slow in my machine. Is there a way to make it faster?

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-12.04, gnome

I have recently installed GNOME 3 on my Ubuntu 12.04 and it seems that most of its fancy effects work pretty smoothly. Strangely though, dragging a window is slow and glitchy. Is it caused by some effect which can be disabled?

Comment: Unfortunately, your question isn't about programming or programming tools, so we can't help you here. However, our friends over at [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/) probably can - be sure to search before asking and [read their FAQ](http://serverfault.com/faq) for help on constructing a good question.

Comment: @j0k [sf]? I think you mean [su]. Or [ubuntu.se] perhaps.

Comment: @j0k Did _you_ read the Server Fault FAQ?

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/545681/fedora-18-severe-overheating-hp-envy-4-1002tx-in-gnome-shell/ This answer might or might not be relevant, but I figured it might. It _appears_ to point to a bug in GNOME.

Answer (score 1):

Slow glitchy window movement used to be a problem with the open source ATI drivers. As GNOME3 now uses OpenGL pretty heavily, do you have the most recent drivers for your graphics card and have you tried with the closed source ones if they are available?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using compiz for the "fancy effects", open a terminal and type ccsm and then play with the settings there. Try disabling the ones involving window effects.

Related info: http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/2756/ubuntu_install_compiz_config_settings_manager_configure_desktop_effects/

Comment: GNOME 3 does not use Compiz.